# matplotlib xkcd with utf-8 label

Tags: python, fonts, python3, matplotlib

In python3 / matplotlib, I'd like a plot with a label:

```
plt.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(1,10)), label='fête')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Works great. Now let's try with xkcd mode:

```
plt.xkcd()
plt.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(1,10)), label='fête')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

No error, but the label is 'f?te'. It seems likely that this is a font problem rather than a matplotlib problem, based on reaction to this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723065/matplotlib-xkcd-with-utf-8-label).

That said, I tried writing the word 'fête' in libreoffice with font humor sans, and no UTF-8'ish problems apparent (i.e., accents display correctly).

Comment: A commenter on SO suggests this works in libreoffice because LO uses a backup font that has the needed symbols.  Commenter suggests this is a font problem ubuntu-side.  In which case, the question is how to file a bug against a font.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723065/matplotlib-xkcd-with-utf-8-label/30293106?iemail=1&noredirect=1#30293106